# Logstash Merge Field With Root Object

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I have logstash input that looks like this

```
{
    "@timestamp": "2016-12-20T18:55:11.699Z",
    "id": 1234,
    "detail": {
        "foo": 1
        "bar": "two"
    }
}
```

I would like to merge the content of **"detail"** with the root object so that the final event looks like this:

```
{
    "@timestamp": "2016-12-20T18:55:11.699Z",
    "id": 1234,
    "foo": 1
    "bar": "two"
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without writing my own filter plugin?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this with a ruby filter.

`filter {
    ruby {
        code => "
            event['detail'].each {|k, v|
                event[k] = v
            }
            event.remove('detail')
        "
    }
}`

Comment: In logstash version 5, the syntax has been changed to like this `code => "event.get('detail').each {|k, v| event.set(k, v) } event.remove('detail')"`

Comment: wish Logstash itself had some feature

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to do that using the `json_encode` plugin (not included by default).

The `json` extractor add fields to the root of the event. It's one of the very few extractors that can add things to the root.

```
filter {
    json_encode {
        source => "detail"
        target => "detail"
    }

    json {
        source => "detail"
        remove_field => [ "detail" ]
    }
}
```