# move json fields to root - logstash

Tags: logstash

my logs contain nested json under `det` field

```
{
        "id" => "1234",
        "@version" => "1",
        "@timestamp" => "2015-05-27T03:45:33.094Z",
        "det" => {
                    "name" => "jim",
                    "a" => "11111",
                    "b" => "222222",
                    "c" => "33333"
        }
}
```

I would like to move all keys under `det` to root. (dynamically, without the need to mention child key names)

**result:**

```
{
        "id" => "1234",
        "@version" => "1",
        "@timestamp" => "2015-05-27T03:45:33.094Z",
        "name" => "jim",
        "a" => "11111",
        "b" => "222222",
        "c" => "33333"

}
```

what filter can I use?

Comment: Once [my PR](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-mutate/issues/90) gets merged, you'll be able to use the `mutate/copy` filter :-)

Comment: Pending Val's awesome PR to mutate, this has already been asked and answered for logstash 2.x http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41251703/logstash-merge-field-with-root-object